# EditText with button and icon and label in border

Tags: xml

Hello how can i do a input like this image?[image: images]

Comment: What it the connection to xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to a material text field. Here's the [documentation](https://material.io/components/text-fields#outlined-text-field).

It would provide you with enough documentation for how to implement it.

The one you want to look for is the `outlined text field`

Just go to the implementation section of the page.

But, I don't think you can add text in the right section.

The one with the `mes contacts` written in it.

basically I am not sure you can add the `mes contacts` text.

I'm not sure of whether material library allows that.

Comment: Thank you Vaishnav Kanhirathingal it help me

Comment: just tick mark the answers which are appropriate/correct. You aren't actually meant to say thank you, etc on this site (you're welcome btw) because those comments can cause confusions between what are genuine questions and what are less meaningful to others. So, the correct way would be something like - an upvote( the upward arrow) if the answer was a good attempt and a tick mark if the answer actually solved your issue.